# Implications Of Peak Humans in Sports

Tags: biology, near-future, science-in-society, genetic-engineering, futurology

In a world where genetic mods can substancially alter people's physiology even after they've reached maturity, do you think that sports that are physical conditioning based will die out in favor of skill ones based since every athlete will reach peak human physical?

Or maybe there isn't such thing as "peak human potential" and every athlete will have a team of genetic engineers behind, always making tweaks and pushing the boundaries of what's biologically possible, even borrowing genes from animals in some form of biomimicry?

In this world, genetic enhancement extended human expiration date in face of AI and Androids, and cibernetic implants took care of things that would be impossible to achieve organically, like brain-(computer/machine/brain) interfaces.

Comment: In the Paralympics athletes are split into many classifications based on their impairment. In a world where physical enhancements from implants give athletes an advantage over non enhanced, they may have also have many classifications for the different types of enhancements and implants for all events.

Comment: *"do you think that sports ... will die out"* We're not a discussion site. Don't ask people to share their thoughts on what may happen. We are worldbuilders we can build a world where sports will die out, and build a world where they will not. In your world you get to decide which it will be.

Comment: VTC Too Story-Based. We've already solved this problem today. We outlaw modifications because "peak" performance isn't something that can be bought. It can only be something that can be trained. Of course, we have our cheaters, too, who are willing to pay for modifications to win. But that's a story choice, not a worldbuilding rule. You're not asking about a worldbuilding rule. "implications" are something you, the storybuilder, can decide on at whim. They don't reflect rules.

Answer (score 8):

### They would create new sports divisions

In the real world we already separate athletes into categories based on factors that could effect thier performance.  Genders, handicaps, etc.  We would simply add new sports leagues for enhanced athletes.

[image]

We already see something very much like this in Paralympics where competition is about a mix of athletic determination AND technology. The quality of an athletes spring blades, wheel chair, etc. matters but who wins is still strongly credited to the skill and mental fortitude of the athlete.  The thing you see in sports like this is that pretty much everyone is already packing cutting edge technology; so, even if one team comes up with something a bit better, the increments tend to be small.

So when you have a Biotech M4A2 competing against a EgenLabs Type-7 bioenhancement package, you know both biotech companies are throwing the best technology available at the problem, and while each bioenhancement package has its advantages and disadvantages, what people will really care about is the choices made by the athletes to min-max those differences into victory retaining the human element of sports appeal to fans.

So the concern is not would these leagues exist (they will), so much as would they become dominant, and that boils down largely to the culture of your people.  If your population maintains a taboo about bioenhancement, then it will probably just be a fringe culture thing.  But, if it becomes a widely accepted thing that people just do (like getting Lasik eye surgery), then these leagues will widely replace unmodified sports in popular culture and the unmodified invalids being both rare and disadvantaged will have to compete in thier own divisions of the Paralympics but will generally never become super rich or famous off of thier skills because watching unmodified sports would to the spectator who is used to the alternative, feel like watching a high school football game when you could be watching the NFL.

Comment: +1 Divisions will also be based on which mods are permitted. If we look at motorsports (Formula 1 etc.) we can see that engineers generally can't throw in everything that they can think of into car design.

Answer (score 2):

No, there will always be a place for unmodified sports I would think.

Most countries have a drug free weight lifting federation for example due to the prevalence of steroid taking weight lifters. They've been around for decades and won't be leaving any time soon. They would find a way to test for modifications as well.

Olympics and others drug test players and would also check for modifications.

Answer (score 2):

## Handicap:

I would guess that sports would, paradoxically, become dominated by the unmodified. I would suggest a scoring system would evolve based on the underlying abilities assessed for each athlete. Sure Polly Puregenes can run a mile in 15 seconds. Ho, hum. But Bob Bumgenes has a heart condition and a predisposition to anxiety. He totally beat the spread by three minutes!

This would mean the athletes would be being evaluated for their underlying genetics, which would be a matter of wide public record. No doubt gene doping would be a problem. Athletes who suffered serious injuries that affect their performance might become MORE popular and successful as people rally to them overcoming adversity.

There would probably still be a market for the perfect people doing sports perfectly. The all-drug, all-gene all-enhancement crowd could certainly showcase the limits of human ability (probably sponsored by the drug and genetics companies selling various enhancements). It would stop being about scores and become more like pure entertainment. Occasionally a new enhancement would create a flurry of excitement as records were broken.

But the challenge of human determination, of overcoming adversity, would mean you would look to those less capable to exceed the limits of what they should be able to do and achieve all that they personally can be.

Hey did you hear the scandal with David Disabled? He broke his own knee to compete in the crippling injury class and has been disqualified!

Comment: David Disabled is all like, "But I Identify as a cripple you hateful bigots!"